# Python's request.get became extremely slow

Tags: python-3.x

for some reason suddenly request.get takes ~3 minutes to return, I've tried multiple sites 
I also noticed pip takes 4-6 minutes to upgrade packages, my internet connection hasn't changed 
I'm lost here I can't figure this out.